# Как программно вызвать клик из CSS?

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser, css, javascript

Добрый день!
Пишу программу для автоматизации рутины на c#. Присутствует контрол webBrowser.

Столкнулся с задачей:
Необходимо программно вызвать действие при нажатии на элемент html-страницы.
Элемент - текст в теге

```
<span class=MyClass>Нажми</span>
```

В хроме при просмотре кода этого элемента я нашёл вкладку EventListener, где при клике вызывается функция из ява-скрипт файла.

```
function (t){return typeof he===X||t&&he.event.triggered===t.type?e:he.event.dispatch.apply(u.elem,arguments)}
```

Проанализировать файл не получается - слишком обфусцирован, можно ли программно "симулировать" нажатие?

Comment: Спасибо подсказку) я нашёл решение на JS
document.getElementsByClassName("g-switcher m-switcher_999 noprint HH-Resume-Touch-Button")[0].click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил задачу по-другому: отправлял правильные http запросы серверу, изначально проанализировал при помощи fiddler. Стало намного быстрее.

Answer (score 5):

Из CSS вызвать клик нельзя, т.к. CSS это не язык программирования (формальный язык описания внешнего вида документа).
А вот из JS, обратившись к классу кнопки, можно ее нажать или из jQuery:

```
$('.MyClass').click(); // jQuery пример
```

Comment: Интересно, что при прохождении теста на знание CSS Htmlbook выдает ошибку, если имена классов начинаются с заглавной буквы. Чисто для себя хочу понять, можно ли начинать класс с заглавной буквы или нет?

Comment: @Olga Moscow, можно.

Comment: Значит, htmlbook не прав, ReinRaus, спасибо!